# how to go on previous screen from current screen in Android app

Tags: android, android-activity

How do I go to previous screen from current screen in Android app? I know there is a back button on phone, but it takes me to beginning screen of my app and I want my buttons on app to work for going back to previous screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Back button indeed takes you to previously seen activity on screen, that launched the current one (not by means of back button). If back button takes you to beggining screen of your app means that navigation to your last activity was done from it. Try launching an activity from another one different from start activity.

What really can be problematic is ending application once at start activity by pressing back button and discovering the application switching to activity that lauched start activity (not by means of back button). In this case you should just call `finish()` inside `onDestroy()` listener method of your start activity.

Comment: Thanks, I got this as soon as I posted the question. But your answer was correct too.